# problema instalar vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify, yarn

despues de instalar `@vue/cli` ejecuto el comando

```
vue -V
```

pero me manda el siguiente error:

> vue : El término 'vue' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable.
> Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e
> inténtelo de nuevo.

ya revisé el path y tengo este:

```
C:\Users{userName}\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no sabemos como lo instalaste ni tu entorno como para saber que pasa...

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar instalarlo global, primero, desintalarlo de tu paquete

```js
npm uninstall vue-cli -g
```

ahora instalarlo global

```js
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

Para confirmar tipea en tu terminal de consola

```js
vue --version
```

Comment: ya funcionó, muchas gracias

Comment: @user286929 me alegra que esta respuesta te funcionara. Por favor, márcala como aceptada y considera darle un voto positivo. Lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](/help/someone-answers) para más información.